# Android: how to import org.python ? What about Pickle (or cPickle)?

Tags: java, android, python, serialization, jython

With raspberry, in order to serialize and exchange some information between devices inside the same network, I'm using python cPickle.

Now, I'd like to send some data to raspberrys using my android device.
Problem is: I did not found a cPickle serializer/deserializer in Android.

I found a cPickle.java class ([documentation](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/modules/cPickle.html) , [code](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiO6JekwYvKAhVHuhQKHex7ACwQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2Fjhawk%2Fmnt%2Fspo%2Fjython%2FjythonRelease_2_2alpha1%2Fsrc%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fpython%2Fmodules%2FcPickle.java&usg=AFQjCNH5kS31P7NfgLSFqyr9RxCr00oD8A&sig2=58x7RwzeNpa0HWp94hDT1A&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU&cad=rja)) that need:

```
import org.python.core.*;
import org.python.core.imp;
```

"python" symbol could not be resolved...

Question are:

- does someone could suggest an Android cPickle compatible serialized/deserializer ?
- how I can import org.python* stuffs (Android-studio newbie step-bystep instruction please)?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Till now I did not solve the problem.
I rewrite code and packet data without pickle...